# Editing e-mails in your browser using (g)vim

Tags: vim, editor

Long ago, I was using the hack given in http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip805 . This hack allowed me to edit any active window frame using gvim. For instance, I was able to edit my gmail replies using gvim.

Unfortunately, the hack does not work to me any more. Is there any other way to achieve the same? Or at least to achieve the same using some concrete browser (for example, firefox)?

Comment: did you try "It's all text" plugin for firefox??

Comment: @Kent: Unfortunaley it does not work with gmail.

Comment: you are using new compose UI. switch back to the old and try again. if you edit email with vim, you don't care about the UI any way.

Comment: @Ken: I am using the old style in gmail.

Answer (score 1):

### Google Chrome

you can use [GhostText](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText) with running server [vim-ghost](https://github.com/falstro/ghost-text-vim). Its not ideal, but allow to interactively use external editor (text is automatically copied to a web textarea element each return to normal mode).

---

Vim-ghost is written in tcl so you need install tcl.
In my case I have tcl installed but without [standard library tcllib](https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcllib/). So I found lacking packages in tcllib (`tcllib/module/sha1` and `tcllib/module/json`) and copy them to a folder listed in tcl path (the first result of `echo $tcl_pkgPath`). More info: `man pkg_mkIndex` or [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl31.html).

Of course vim-ghost server must be run (eg. in autorun script):

```
~/.ghost-text-server.tcl &
```

---

You can also like [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb) to navigate through web using links, tabs, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>gg</kbd> and many vim-like features.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [vimperator](http://www.vimperator.org/vimperator)( [pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/index), which is a fork of vimperator). They offer the ability to edit text boxes, but also offers several additional functions that allow you to control firefox in a similar way to Vim.

If you prefer Vim only for edit text boxes you could try the firefox plugin "It's all text", as mentioned by Kent.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [It's All Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) plugin for Firefox.

Comment: Just checked and sadly it doesn't work for me either=/ See the related issue: https://github.com/docwhat/itsalltext/issues/36 for some tips.